# Extracted iPhone OS images showing as 0x0

Tags: ios, iphone, ftp, filesystems, jailbreak

when i try to download a image from my iPhone (Drop Pin Marker) through a FTP client the file always shows up on my desktop as width-0 height-0. It can be viewed on a internal file system viewer fine but when it gets to my desktop it has no size. Why is this and how can I open these files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's an image, the iphone does some interesting things with png's. It inverts some of the color channels somehow. Here's some info on it http://modmyi.com/wiki/index.php/Iphone_PNG_images

Comment: what specific file (and path) are you trying to pull off there? I used "iPhone Explorer" from iphone-explorer.com and was able to pull the SmallPinPurple.png from the /Applications/maps.app on iOS4 and its clear but it has the proper size attributes and the SmallPinGreen.png from OS 3.1.3 and it also has the proper size constraints.

Comment: More importantly, "iPhone PNGs" have a "CgBI" chunk before the IHDR chunk. A valid PNG **must** start with an IHDR chunk; some viewers might ignore this constraint and parse the IHDR chunk while others will report an error/zero size/whatever.

Comment: I am trying to extract "/System/Library/Frameworks/Mapkit.framwork/**A large red pin with a shadow**"   (Typing from memory)